# Materialize data from cache table to production table [PostgreSQL]

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers, materialized-views

I am trying to find the best solution (perfomance/easy code) for the following situation:

Considering a database system with two tables, A (production table) and A'(cache table):

- Future rows are added first into A' table in order to not disturb the production one.
- When a timer says go (at midnight, for example) rows from A' are incorporated to A.
  Dealing with duplicates, inexistent rows, etc have to be considerated.

I've been reading some about Materialized Views, Triggers, etc. The problem is that I should not introduce so much noise in the production table because is the reference table for a server (a PowerDNS server in fact).

So, what do you guys make of it? Should I better use triggers, MV, or programatically outside of the database?? (I'm using python, BTW)

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: I don't understand the part with *in order to not disturb the production one*. How does an insert "disturb" the table?

Comment: The usual paradigm is to insert into the real table and have a cached materialized view for reads. Not the other way around. The DB has to really know the actually state of things. If things go booboo there may be no way to reconstruct the DB to a consistent state with things waiting around to be inserted.

Comment: I see the point of your comments, maybe is not a good idea calling it 'cache table'. You'll understand better if you think about it as a table which collects future changes that will be materialized some time after. You have actual values that are still valid. The day after the future values become actual values, overwriting the ones which were actual values till then.
Apart from that, as I said, the system is suposed to answer queries from a dns server. If we let administrators to free make changes into production table, performance could be affected.

Comment: If you want to control the time when a new row is seen as "active" in the system, why not simply have a flag that is flipped once the row should be used? How many rows do you expect in that table? Unless we are talking billions of rows, or thousands of inserts per second, I don't believe this premature optimization will do any good.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" solution according to the criteria you've laid out so far would just be to insert into the production table.

...unless there's actually something extremely relevant you're not telling us

Comment: The reason for using two tables is to deacople as much as I can the insertions done by administrator with the queries done by users.

Comment: I'm still not really getting the reason for this decoupling.  Most tables in most databases in use have users/admins/whoever updating and others querying at the same time.  That's what they're designed to do.